# Browser extension. Inject unremovable html element

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, opera, inject

In firefox extension, I can inject html elements using javascript so that they can appear on the webpage area but are not seen by document (I can do this by injecting it into the browser's parent.)

Example:

```
injectNode = gBrowser.getBrowserAtIndex(index).parentNode;
injectNode.appendChild(injectedElement);
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Opera and Chrome ?

Comment: I don't think so. This method is part of XUL and not HTML DOM. Maybe you describe why do you need this?

Comment: Because I don't want to have injected html elements removed by javascript on webpage (if someone will try to)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are more casual ways of achieving this. For example, a timer that would check the element and revive it if some script have hidden/removed it. Anyway it is off-topic here, you can start a new question which I will follow because the subject is quite interesting.